# How to save and load presets of Android activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, save, load

I have an Activity that consists of multiple containers (FrameLayouts, more specifically) in order to display Fragments. These Fragments are actually audio effects, so once I choose a number of fragments to show in their corresponding containers and adjust their knobs (typical guitar effects stuff), I would like to save and load their presets.

In another words, I want to save the view of my Activity (with data of which effect is in which container, what values are the knobs etc.) to a file, and then load the file. On load, I would like my Activity to switch to the view I saved in file.

I have made the interface for saving and loading, but I can't find a way to save and load my views. I've found numerous examples of saving and loading views on orientation change, but not one example of saving and loading in files.

Here are the snippets of my code for saving and loading, too bad it doesn't work. Actually, this was just "mushed" by me via some marginal instructions I've found on the internet, perhaps I couldn't be farther from the answer:

```
public void save_file (Object file, String fileName, Context context)  {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(MainActivity.this);
        oos.writeObject(file);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
        if (fileName != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Save successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Enter name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static MainActivity load_file(String fileName, Context context) {

    MainActivity Main = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Main = (MainActivity) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Main;
}
```

I also don't know a way to switch a view to the loaded one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So right now it looks like all you're doing is creating a new instance of MainActivity in load_file, but that's not really going to do you any good.  In Android, you don't deal with creating instances of your Activity classes, the system will do that for you.

It sounds to me like for what you're trying to do, you should be using the shared preferences to store the information about your views, then re-render the Views with all the proper values in the onCreate method of MainActivity.  If you're unfamiliar with SharedPreferences, you can look at the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Basically, it's just writing to a file like you're already doing, but abstracted a little so that it's more convenient.  You want to have a field in MainActivity called mPrefs, initialize it in onCreate like this:

```
mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(<unique name here>, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

For example, say a user adjusts a guitar knob to a tension of 6 (I'm imagining that gets stored as an int)

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
//you should actually store the key string "guitar_knob_1" as a static final global variable rather than hard-coding
editor.putInt("guitar_knob_1", 6);
editor.commit();
```

Now, back in onCreate, you can have something like this:

```
if(mPrefs.getInt("guitar_knob_1", -1) != -1) { //-1 is the value we get if nothing is stored there
  //set the knob to the value we read
}
```

The way it would make sense to me to do what you're asking would be to store a String of the names of the Views you have associated with each FrameLayout, then write some functions to render the correct Views in onCreate.  You don't really need to "save" the views, just save all the values associated with them and rebuild them correctly when the activity opens.  Hope that helps!